# test_helper don't load when I make a test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I need make a test of a model, but when I do this:

```
ruby test/unit/user_test.rb
```

I have also tried with other methods:

```
ruby -I test test/unit/user_test.rb
rake test:units TEST=test/unit/user_test.rb
```

But anyone make the test and said:

> test/unit/user_test.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)

Or like.

This is part of the code (only the beginning):

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = true
  fixtures :users

  def test_auth 
    #check that we can login we a valid user 
    assert_equal  @bob, User.authenticate("bob", "test")    
    #wrong username
    assert_nil    User.authenticate("nonbob", "test")
    #wrong password
    assert_nil    User.authenticate("bob", "wrongpass")
    #wrong login and pass
    assert_nil    User.authenticate("nonbob", "wrongpass")
  end
```

Yours sincerely

Comment: Do you actually have a file called `test/test_helper.rb`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this require:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem has been solved, I have other, but it's nothing for this, I try to solve.

Comment: Why is this problem occurring and why does this fix it?!

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8, if you run your test cases with

```
$ rake test
```

it won't be an issue.

Comment: Yes - definitely most times you need this command to run the full test suite. But often if you're working on getting a test to work in a single test-file, it's often good to just run just that one test file while you make your changes... then get back to running the full test-suite once you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

for a single file

$ rake test TEST=test/unit/glosentry_test.rb

for all file

$ rake test